# ¿Cómo aparecer un botón cuando se escriba dentro de un input?

Tags: javascript, html, css, typescript

es sencillo lo que quiero lograr pero quiero saber de que formas lo harían ustedes, quiero que al escribir dentro de un input aparezca un botón y que cuando el input este vacío pues desaparezca

```html
<input type="password" placeholder="Contraseña"> <button>mostrar</button>
```

la verdad es que tengo que aplicarlo para angular pero aun así de cualquier forma que lo puedan hacer me sirve saberlo ya sea con typescript o javascript, gracias de antemano

Comment: Qué has intentado? Qué palabras usaste en google? Ya llevas ocho meses en el sitio, y al menos cuatro preguntas. Ya sabes que debes escribir el código que has intentado.

Comment: Recuerda que tu pregunta no debe parecer [un ticket para desarrollo](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433). Muestra un [repro] de lo que has intentado hasta el momento, y el problema _específico_ que has tenido. No coloques cualquier código en la pregunta porque sí.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si, es sencillo. En primera instancia requieres validar que exista el valor del input, eso lo hacemos de la siguiente forma:

```
<input type="password" name="inputvalor" id="inputvalor" placeholder="Contraseña">
<button type="button" id="buttonvalor" style="display:none;">mostrar</button>
```

En javascript, escribes lo siguiente:

```
input=document.getElementById('inputvalor').value;
boton=document.getElementById('buttonvalor');
if(input.length > 0){
 button.style.display = 'inline'
}else{
 button.style.display = 'none'
}
```

Primero, recibimos el valor del input con la variable input.
Luego, recibimos la etiqueta del botón.
Validamos si el input tiene algo, si es así, muestra el botón, si no es así, oculta el botón..

Comment: Evita responder a preguntas en donde el autor de la misma no haya expuesto sus intentos en resolver su planteamiento. Lee [answer], en especial la sección _contesta preguntas **bien formadas**_.

Comment: muchas gracias, las dos formas me ayudaron a aprender algo nuevo y las dos formas me pueden funcionar, :D

Answer (score 0):

Espero que esto te sirva:

```
<body>
    <input type="text" name="name"  class="input" > 
    <button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" class="button" hidden disabled>Submit</button>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var input = document.querySelector('input');
        var button = document.querySelector('button');
input.onclick = function() {
  button.disabled = false;
  button.hidden = false;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Evita responder a preguntas en donde el autor de la misma no haya expuesto sus intentos en resolver su planteamiento. Lee [answer], en especial la sección _contesta preguntas **bien formadas**_.

Comment: @padaleiana me parece correcto, pero sabia la respuesta y creía que podía ayudar